# This is my code and it is returning Process returned 255(0xff) codeblocks

Tags: c++

I have written code for reading a text file containing 37000 DNA sequences and analyzing the sequences for specific pattern . But every time I run the code it says

`codon.exe stopped working and Process returned 255 (0xff)`

This is the code :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<cstring>
#include<cstdio>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

 ifstream dnafile;
dnafile.open("code.txt");            /// code.txt is notepad file name
if(!dnafile.is_open())
{
    cout<<"file not opened";
}

int c=0;
vector <int> a;
vector <char> codon;

int l=0; /// lTH  TERM OF DNA SEQUENCE
char x;
while((x = dnafile.get()) != EOF)   /// READING CHARACTER BY CHARACER FROM FILE
{
   if(x=='>')
   {
       l=0;
       codon.push_back('#');
       continue;
   }
       l++;
       codon.push_back(x);
}
for(int l=0;l<codon.size();l++)
{
    if(codon.at(l)=='#')
        c++;
}
int c1[c+1];
float b[c+1],d[c+1];

for(int j=0;j<(c+1);j++)
{
    for(int i=1;i<a.size();i++)
    {
        if (a[i]==0&&c1[j]!=0)
        {
            d[j]=(b[j]+a[i-c1[j]])/c1[j];
            i++;
            break;
        }
        else if(c1[j]==0)
            d[j]=0;
        else
        {
            b[j]=b[j]+(a[i]-a[i-1]);
        }
    }
    continue;

}
for(int j=0,i=0;j<a.size(),i<(c+1);j=j+c1[i],i++)
{
    cout<<"("<<d[i]<<","<<c1[i]<<","<<a[j]<<")"<<", ";
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Start by using the debugger, and find where it crashes.

Comment: `int c1[c+1];`  This line and lines looking like this are not valid C++.  Why not use `vector`?  You're using it in other places, so why not here also?  `std::vector<int> c1(c+1);`

Comment: even if I declare them as vectors it will not affect also in arrays it is easy initialise them some values

Comment: @AyushKumar - There is a big advantage if you changed to `std::vector`, and that advantage is that you would have a chance to figure out the error much more easily than using dumb (variable length) arrays.  The reason is that `std::vector` has an `at()` function that tests if your indices are within bounds.  Using arrays, you get no such test.  There is a very good chance that your error occurs because you are using an array index that's out-of-bounds, and using plain arrays are not going to tell you if you're doing so or not.

Comment: @AyushKumar And [here it is](http://ideone.com/H1qfuS).  I changed to `std::vector`, and I used `at()` on the last `cout` line.  Look at the exception that's thrown -- an `out_of_range` exception, indicating **exactly** what I described.  You are going out-of-bounds of your array (now changed to `vector`).  The `a` vector / array is empty, and you're trying to access `a[0]`, which does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

[Updated Code](http://ideone.com/e.js/rpg12O)

Well I found two mistakes in it that you're making here and that's variable length array. You'd be getting an error on

```
int c1[c+1];
float b[c+1],d[c+1];
```

Update it to be a dynamic array like this, since c is a variable and is assigned a value at RunTime.
It'll only work if c is a const. For a variable you'd get *C++ forbids variable length array*

```
int *c1 = new int[c+1];
float *b = new float[c+1], *d = new float[c+1];
```

and don't forget to deallocate the memory in the end

```
delete [] c1;
delete [] b;
delete [] d;
```

Or you can use STL library as a workaround.
`vector<int>` or `vector<float>` would also work since they can update their size as you push elements into them

Also where you are checking your file existence

```
if(!dnafile.is_open())
{
    cout<<"file not opened";
}
```

Add an else statement like this, since the code afterwards runs (in your implementation) even if the file is not found after printing "file not found"

```
else {
    int c=0;
    // all the code
    delete [] c1;
    delete [] b;
    delete [] d;
}
return 0;
```

Comment: I applied your suggestions, even after that there is runtime error and debugging shows breakpoint at this line:                                                                    else
        {
            b[j]=b[j]+(a[i]-a[i-1]);
        }                                                                                                                     and it is showing still not working properly error.

Comment: GCCTACTTCATCTCAGGACCCGCCCAAGAGTGGCCGCGGCTTTGGGACACCTGGGGTCGGGTCCACCATGAGGATAAAACCTCCTTCTCTTCTGGACATGTCCAGGAGTGGCCGTTGCTACAAGTCACCTGGTGCTACGACCAGGGTGAGAATAAAGACGTCTCCTCAGGACCCTCCCAGGAGAGTACATGGCATTGAGACATCTGGCGGCCAAGTGAGGAAAAGACACCCTGTCTGCAGCACCCAGAACTGAGGAGGGGCACTGCCCTGGGCCTTACTTCCCAGCCCTGGCCTCCAATTCTGACCTTACAAAAGTGTCCCTTGAGTGAGGCAGTGACCACGCATTGTCACAGCTACCAAAGTGTGGTTTGCAGATGATCTGGGCTTGTTTCTGGCAGAGATTCTGGTACAGAGAAAGGAGAGGCGCTGAGTGGAACACGATGGGCTGAGGCCAGGGGAGACATCACAACCTCCAACAACACTTTTTTCATGCTTTAATAACTCATTTTTCTTAGAGAACTAAAGTAGTTGAAACAATATAGAAACATTTTTTAAGTA

Comment: @V.404 Much better help would be if the OP changed to `std::vector` and used `at()` instead of `[ ]` to access the vector.  Look at my comment in the main section -- doing that would have detected at least one error.

Comment: You're getting Segmentation Fault in your last cout loop. That in this case means you're accessing some array index which is not there, caused by ', i < (c + 1)' . That kinda thing is easy to handle with at() as @PaulMcKenzie said.

Comment: [Updated Code](http://ideone.com/e.js/rpg12O) This is same as @PaulMcKenzie 's implementation version with try-throw-catch.

Comment: Also I hope you do know that ',' in for loop just checks the last condition and thus your condition of "j < a.size(), i<(c+1)" is not checked. I think you were going for a '&&' there.